# Xml data is converted into Json data in android

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing

I need to parse XML data from a web service. But, when I am getting the data from the web service the data comes in the format of JSON (In the browser I am seeing the data as XML). So, please guide me how to get xml data into my application.

I am using the following.

**In my main activity:**

```
static final String URL = "http://nclex.testshell.net/api/resources";
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Log.e("Response is...",xml);
```

**My xmlParser class**

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }
}
```

**output response is**

> [{"ResourceId":1,"Title":"GRE revised General Test","Description":"The
>   Verbal Reasoning section of the GRE  revised General
>   Test","Link":"http://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/about/content/verbal_reasoning"},{"ResourceId":2,"Title":"GRE Power Pre","Description":"GRE Power
>   Pre","Link":"http://www.number2.com/exams/gre/companion/index.cfm?s=0"},{"ResourceId":3,"Title":"GRE Analytical Writing","Description":"GRE Analytical
>   Writing","Link":"http://www.mygretutor.com/tests.aspx"},{"ResourceId":4,"Title":"GATE
>   Architecture & Planning","Description":"GATE Architecture &
>   Planning","Link":"http://www.onestopgate.com/gate-sample-papers/architecture-planning/"},{"ResourceId":5,"Title":"TarGATE","Description":"GATE
>   to acheive your
>   target","Link":"http://gateforum.com/Testseries-Venue.php"},{"ResourceId":6,"Title":"TOEFL
>   iBT","Description":"TOEFL iBT  Test Sample
>   Questions","Link":"https://www.ets.org/toefl/ibt/prepare/sample_questions"}]

Comment: This is done by web service. Modify your webservice code...

Comment: Thankyou for ur quick response, then how to change my webservice code

Comment: view your code of web service. There would be a code that checks incoming response, and look into flags or headers which tells that service "if desktop app requesting or if mobile app requesting".

Answer (score 2):

***The type or format of data you retrieved from the server using web service is totally depends on the language in which web service is implemented and the response code that web service choose to format the data.***.

Older web services or platforms mainly supports XML format.And the new web services uses the Json format for its light-weight.

In your case,Your web service supports both type of format(XML,Json) and it chooses the format as per the platform from which it receives the request(Mobile,Desktop).(May be it acts as a *Generic Webservice*).

One way to test the webservice response is to requesting  it from platform browser i.e use your platform browser(Desktop or mobile) to see the response for your platform.

Finally,Answer to your question,
Change the code at your server side and **make sure that it returns XML data as a response for Mobile platform**(you don't have to worry about the code at your application side;all changes to be done at server side).

However,you can also convert Json to xml as,

```
JSONObject Jobj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Then you can get it in XML format using the XML class, like so:

```
String xml = org.json.XML.toString(Jobj);
```

but it's not recommended as it need extra cpu time to convert Json to xml and it can be a problem if your response data is huge.